# Differentiate polar curve

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have attempted this question but have not found a solution. I am currently stuck. Hints on how I may go further would be helpful. Thank You in advance.

The Question:
[image]

What I have done so far: 
[image]

Comment: Don't believe everything you read in books!

Comment: In the book, what is given as $x$ is $-x$ as you did show. Just mention the error. In any manner, this does not change the stationary points.

Comment: Does this imply that I am right?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I don't clearly understand what you mean by x and -x.

Comment: Yes, you are for sure ! The book is wrong by a factor of $-1$.

Comment: Great, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is correct and is the same way I would have done it.  Once I read Claude Leibovici's comments I figured the problem is with the book.